# Understanding node streams and vinyl-fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm having a weird issue, and I'm not sure where my problem is. Probably it's because I lack understanding of some basics of node streams or vinyl-fs.

Anyway, here is the description:

I'm building different scripts that I would like to use with gulp.

This one, for instance, is building some assets I need; more precisely, I'm copying bootstrap source files from node_modules to my assets folder.

This function should return a promise, this way I can use it with gulp more easily.

This is the sass-bootstrap.js file that will do the job:

- this is a shorter version, there are some checks before, but not related with my question.
- assume all variables defined.

```
var defer    = Q.defer(),
    vinylFs  = require( 'vinyl-fs' ),
    map      = require( 'map-stream' );

function sass_bootstrap() {
  var defer = Q.defer();
  vinylFs.src( [ bootstrap_sass_route + '/**/_*.scss' ] )
    .pipe( vinylFs.dest( assets_sass_bootstrap ) )
    .pipe( map( function( file, cb ) { 
      cb( null, file ); 
    }))
    .on( 'end', function(){
      defer.resolve();
    });
  return defer.promise;
}
```

And this is the gulp task that use it:

- again its a simplified version, whith just the relevant code included

```
gulp.task( 'development', function ( cb ) {

  sass_bootstrap()
    .then( function(){
      cb();
    })
    .catch( function( err ){
      err.log();
      cb();
    });


});
```

This is working good, but I don't quite understand why it doesn't work this way:

```
function sass_bootstrap() {
  var defer = Q.defer();
  vinylFs.src( [ bootstrap_sass_route + '/**/_*.scss' ] )
    .pipe( vinylFs.dest( assets_sass_bootstrap ) )
    .on( 'end', function(){
      defer.resolve();
    });
  return defer.promise;
}
```

Furthermore, I don't understand why I need the call to `map()`. I think on my first example is really not needed at all ...

Any hint or explanation would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of vinyl-fs are you using? There is a (fixed) issue where vfs.dest doesnt end (but map-stream does): https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/issues/120. There is no tagged version with this yet, but try the master branch in your package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was an anti pattern.

We should not mix promises and streams; the correct way of doing this would be to return the stream on sass_bootstrap and listen to end/error events:

**sass-bootstrap.js**

```
var vinylFs  = require( 'vinyl-fs' );

function sass_bootstrap() {
  return vinylFs
    .src( [ bootstrap_sass_route + '/**/_*.scss' ] )
    .pipe( vinylFs.dest( assets_sass_bootstrap ) )
}
```

**gulp task**

```
gulp.task( 'development', function ( cb ) {
  return sass_bootstrap()
    .on( 'end', cb );
    .on( 'error' function( err ) {
      // Do error stuff
      cb( err )
    });
});
```